# NGINX HTTP to HTTPS redirection not working | LetsEncrypt SSL

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, https, lets-encrypt

The site just works fine on https but doesn't respond when using http

https://onsitecourse.com -> This works
http://onsitecourse.com -> This does not work

I have tried a lot of way to bifurcate server blocks for both HTTP and HTTPS, but nothing seems to be working.

My current NGINX config is :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name onsitecourse.com www.onsitecourse.com;
    return 301 https://www.onsitecourse.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    server_name onsitecourse.com www.onsitecourse.com;
    root /var/www/onsiteacademy/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/onsitecourse.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/onsitecourse.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.onsitecourse.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = onsitecourse.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

Would really appreciate some assistance here from anyone!

Comment: What is your third server block for? Looks like it does the same as the first one, mby one of them is unnecessary?

Comment: I'm guessing firewall. Google the name of the distro you are using followed by 'firewall', to check which ports are open/closed